# Django Formset new entry fails validation

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to create a formset where I can 1) show all entries +1 (for new entry) 2) update existing entries 3) add new entries. Currently I can successfully complete 1 & 2. When it comes to adding a new entry the formset fails .is_valid() check. This is because I have a hidden input for the entry_id. The id is necessary for bulk_update() to update existing entries, but causes the is_valid() function to fail on the new entry. If I use bulk_create(), I do not need the id but it will duplicate all existing entries.

Is there a way to pass the .is_valid() check when attempting to add a new entry?

views.py

```
def CustomerView(request):
    template = "accounts/customers.html"
    # Create the formset, specifying the form and formset we want to use.
    CustomerFormSet = formset_factory(CustomerForm, formset=BaseFormSet)

    # Get our existing data for this user.
    customer_list = Customers.objects.all().order_by("cust_name")
    customers = [{'customer_id': c.id, 'customer_name': c.cust_name}
                    for c in customer_list]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        customer_formset = CustomerFormSet(request.POST)
        # print(customer_formset.errors)
        if customer_formset.is_valid():
            # Now save the data for each form in the formset
            customer = []
            
            for customer_form in customer_formset:
                customer_id = customer_form.cleaned_data.get('customer_id')
                customer_name = customer_form.cleaned_data.get('customer_name')
                
                if customer_id and customer_name:
                        customer.append(Customers(id=customer_id, cust_name=customer_name))
            try:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    #Replace the old with the new
                    Customers.objects.filter(id=customer_id).delete()
                    Customers.objects.bulk_create(customer)
                    
                    # And notify our users that it worked
                    messages.success(request, 'Saved Successfully.')

            except IntegrityError: #If the transaction failed
                messages.error(request, 'There was an error saving.')
                return redirect('/customers')
        else: #If the form is not valid
            messages.error(request, 'The form is not valid.')
            
            return redirect('/customers')

    else:
        customer_formset = CustomerFormSet(initial=customers)

    data = {
        'customer_formset': customer_formset,
    }

    return render(request, template, data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the entry_id not required in the form and then you can check it on the view after the validation to decide to update or add the element